# local storage resets after reload

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage, reload

I am an absolute newbie to js. The following code creates an array of objects from user inputs that is saved in `localStorage`.

I want to make `localStorage` to keep data after the page is reloaded.

I searched and found a solution of using
`localStorage.setItem("initData"+new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify(movies))`
This really works but in this case i cant have all objects in an array.

```
    <script>
        
        let movies = [];
        const addMovie = (ev)=>{
            ev.preventDefault();  //to stop the form submitting
            let movie = {
                id: Date.now(),
                title: document.getElementById('title').value,
                sales: document.getElementById('sales').value
            }
            movies.push(movie);
            document.forms[0].reset(); // to clear the form for the next entries
            //document.querySelector('form').reset();

            //for display purposes only
            console.warn('added' , {movies} );
            let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
            pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(movies, '\t', 2);

            //saving to localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify(movies) );


            let allsales = movies.map(({ sales }) => sales)
            var allsalesnumbers = allsales.map(Number);
            var sumSales = allsalesnumbers.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
            console.log("Total of EU Sales " + sumSales );

                       
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
            document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addMovie);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `let movies = [];` because you do nothing with it. You always start with a new array, it does not know it is supposed to use something in localstorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalStorage only stores string, you need to stringify the array before storing and Parse it before reading.

```
let movies =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies')) || [];
```

//saving to localStorage:

localStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(movies) );

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not using the old stored data, just overriding it with new data every time you submit. Try initializing the movies array like this

```
const oldDataString = localStorage.getItem('initData')
const movies = JSON.parse(oldDataString || "[]") // if there is no items just parses an empty array
```

Comment: This one also works as Anya Schechter answer. Thank you!